# Extension tuple in TypeScript 3?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript 3 brings a new feature as extension of tuple to use rest parameters with any type.

It looks like this:

```
function call<TS extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: TS) => R, ...args: TS): R {
    return fn(...args);
}

function foo(x: number, y: string): string {
    return (x + y).toLowerCase();
}

// The `TS` type parameter is inferred as `[number, string]`
let a = call(foo, 100, "Hello");

console.log(a);
```

What is main reason to use it, I can not understand advantage of this code

As I got this right, it allows to pass any parameters to function with any type.

Why dont use simple this, it gives the same result:

```
function call(fn, ...args) {
    return fn(...args);
}
function foo(x: number, y: string, z: string): string {
    return (x + y + z).toLowerCase();
}

// The `TS` type parameter is inferred as `[number, string]`
let a = call(foo, 100, "Hello", "sss");

console.log(a);
```

I think advantage in this:

```
function call<TS extends number[], R>(fn: (...args: TS) => R, ...args: TS): R {
    return fn(...args);
}

function foo(x: number, y: number):number {
    return x + y;
}

function foo2(x: number):number {
    return x;
}

// The `TS` type parameter is inferred as `[number, string]`

let a = call((x: number, y: number) => x + y, 1, 2);
let b = call((x: number) => x, 1);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

When TypeScript automaticly understands which function call depends of parameters.

Comment: "Why don't I simply use this; it gives the same result"?  Because it's not type safe: `call("what","are","you","doing")`;

Comment: Do you mean in this case I can pass any type data?

Comment: Also what does mean: `TS`, and `R`

Comment: Can I use my own TS, R?

Comment: `TS` and `R` are generic parameters.  You can use whatever you want.  I don't understand the question... maybe write some code that shows the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [TypeScript documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) and the [relevant pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) introducing this feature for more information.  Since 2015 there has been an [open feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) in TypeScript, upvoted by hundreds of people, for the ability to manipulate unspecified-length tuples of types, also known as "variadic kinds".

The short answer for why this is desirable is quoted in many of those linked documents:

> With these features it becomes possible to strongly type a number of higher-order functions that transform functions and their parameter lists.

In your example,

```
function call<TS extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: TS) => R, ...args: TS): R {
    return fn(...args);
}
```

the `call()` accepts a function and a list of arguments appropriate for that function.  So this works:

```
call((x: number, y: number) => x + y, 1, 2);
```

But these don't:

```
call((x: number, y: number) => x + y, 1); // error
call((x: number, y: number) => x + y, 1, "whoops"); // error
```

Without tuple rest/spread, you could only strongly type that with a big list of [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), which is tedious and fragile:

```
function call<R>(fn: () => R): R;
function call<T0, R>(fn: (t0: T0) => R, t0: T0): R;
function call<T0, T1, R>(fn: (t0: T0, t1: T1) => R, t0: T0, t1: T1): R;
function call<T0, T1, T2, R>(fn: (t0: T0, t1: T1, t2: T2) => R, t0: T0, t1: T1, t2: T2): R;
// ... more more more 
function call(fn: Function, ...args: any[]): any {
  return fn(...args);
}
```

Anyway, if you don't find it useful, don't use it.  It will probably be most used in libraries, or other places where type manipulation is important.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: You said: `Without tuple rest/spread, you could only strongly type that with a big list of overloads, which is tedious and fragile:`, but anyway I need to modify function: `function foo(x: number, y: string, z: string): string {}` according number of passed parameters.

Comment: I mean in my case I can not call adding a new parameter: `let a = call(foo, 100, "Hello", "sss", "new");` For that I need to modify function. And modify this funtion so many times how much parameters I passed

Comment: Your update illustrates that "`call()` accepts a function and a list of arguments appropriate for that function", so yes, that's a correct way to use it.